# can't get dropdown menu to work using Twitter's Bootstrap

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem getting the dropdown menu to work using Twitter's Bootstrap. Here's my code:

```
<div class="topbar">
<div class="fill">
    <div class="container">
        <h3><a href="index.html">Alex</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">School </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="fall10.html">test link </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="project.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

while I see the proper button "school" on the website, when I click it, there's no dropdown menus that displays the option "test link".

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a reference to the `bootstrap-dropdown.js` file in your head?

```
<script src="1.4.0/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```